# Cassandra SUM(Map <text,int>) is it possible?

Tags: cassandra, cql3, cqlsh

In Casssandra  is it possible to sum of int values in a 
My DB structure is `attr Map<text,int>` is it possible to use 
`select sum (attr['salary']) from testtable` or something equivalent

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cassandra not support Map, List and Set in the Select,Insert with [] ( Ex: attr['salary'] )

You can use User Defined Data Type.

**Example:**

Define your user defined data type like as below

```
mytype {

salary (int)

}
```

create 'attr' field with type 'mytype'

now you can do query like as below

```
select sum(attr.salary) from yourtable.
```

Answer (score 1):

User-Defined Aggregate Function (UDA)